# libwebsockets client fails to connect

Tags: c, libwebsockets

I'm using libwebsockets 2.0 and I'm having a few issues trying to connect to a server using it as a client.

According to the libwebsockets log, this is what happens when my fairly simple client tries to connect to `echo.websocket.org`:

```
[2016/09/25 19:22:56:9033] INFO: lws_header_table_attach: wsi 0x7fe32402a680: ah (nil) (tsi 0, count = 0) in
[2016/09/25 19:22:56:9034] INFO: lws_header_table_attach: wsi 0x7fe32402a680: ah 0x7fe3240078f0: count 1 (on exit)
[2016/09/25 19:22:56:9034] CLIENT: lws_client_connect: direct conn
[2016/09/25 19:22:56:9034] CLIENT: lws_client_connect_2
[2016/09/25 19:22:56:9034] CLIENT: lws_client_connect_2: address 
[2016/09/25 19:22:56:9044] ERR: getaddrinfo failed
Callback LWS_CALLBACK_CLIENT_CONNECTION_ERROR (1)
Connection error: (25) getaddrinfo (ipv4) failed
```

According to this log, it appears to say that `getaddrinfo` failed, but the line above it (which is supposed to output the address which libwebsockets is connecting to) is returning an empty string.

Even weirder, when I run my test code through Valgrind, everything appears to work fine:

```
[2016/09/25 19:46:17:7566] INFO: lws_header_table_attach: wsi 0x6714970: ah (nil) (tsi 0, count = 0) in
[2016/09/25 19:46:17:7598] INFO: lws_header_table_attach: wsi 0x6714970: ah 0x65b35c0: count 1 (on exit)
[2016/09/25 19:46:17:7665] CLIENT: lws_client_connect: direct conn
[2016/09/25 19:46:17:7670] CLIENT: lws_client_connect_2
[2016/09/25 19:46:17:7680] CLIENT: lws_client_connect_2: address echo.websocket.org
[2016/09/25 19:46:17:9511] DEBUG: insert_wsi_socket_into_fds: 0x6714970: tsi=0, sock=6, pos-in-fds=1
```

All of the included examples/tests work just fine, so I'm really not sure where my problem is.

The code at fault is [here](https://github.com/FiniteReality/disccord/blob/master/src/websocket.c) - I'm not sure whether the issue is within my code or whether it's a library issue.

Comment: "but the line above it (which is supposed to output the address which libwebsockets is connecting to) is returning an empty string." - well then there's your problem, an empty string is presumably not a valid address. You should try connecting to a non-empty address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was pondering over my code today, trying random things to see if it would fix the issue. Turns out a `free` in my code was causing issues with libwebsockets:

```
char* address_internal = malloc(strlen(address) + 1);
memcpy(address_internal, address, strlen(address));

/*...*/

free(address_internal);
```

Removing `free(address_internal);` allows the code to work correctly outside of Valgrind.

I'm guessing the problem is that `lws_parse_uri` doesn't create its own internal copy, which the docs don't clearly mention. What's weird is that Valgrind didn't pick up on this, and somehow allowed the memory to still be used.